# How do you prevent a Kendo UI combobox from refilling on Data Read?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo UI to implement a couple of comboboxes on my page. The second combobox relies on the value of the first to populate, but I do not want to use the "Cascade" option, since the second combobox should not ever be disabled.

My issue is the following:
On change of combobox A, combobox B should populate with appropriate values in its dropdown, but the box itself should be clear. I clear the text and value of Combobox B, but when I run a datasource Read or anything, the combobox is refilled with old text.

Subentity is Combobox B:

```
    var subentity = $('#subentity').getKendoComboBox();

    $("#subentity").val(null);
    subentity.value(null);

    subentity.dataSource.data({});

    subentity.text('');
```

I have tried several options, and moving where the values are cleared around, and can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: Combobox B (subentity) is initialized as follows:

```
$("#subentity").kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "--- Enter a Sub-Entity ---",
    autoBind: false,
    animation: false,
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: ResolveUrl('~/Entity/GetSubentities')
            },
            parameterMap: function () {
                return {
                    entityId: $('#hdnEntityId').val(),
                    subentityName: $("#subentity").data("kendoComboBox").text()
                }
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    delay: 500,
    change: onChangeOfSubentityCombo,
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
    value: $('#hdnSubentityName').val()
});
```

Comment: Could you make a fully working example in jsFiddle or jsBin or something? It is unclear where you are getting the new values for dropdown B when dropdown A changes, and where you are doing a dataSource.read()

Comment: @CodingWithSpike It might be difficult to make a Fiddle since I'm pulling the info from a DB through an MVC controller. I've updated my question with the subentity datasource, which I hope helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your value is being replaced with this line.

```
value: $('#hdnSubentityName').val()
```

change it to

```
value:""
```

This will cause your "--- Enter a Sub-Entity ---" field to display however, you can also set the placeholder to blank.

```
placeholder: ""
```

Comment: Days I've been working on this. Days. Thank you so much!